# How does %NNN$hhn work in a format string?

Tags: printf, string-formatting

I am trying out a classic format string vulnerability. I want to know how exactly the following format string works:

> "%NNN$hhn" where 'N' is any number.
>
> E.g: printf("%144$hhn",....);

How does it work and how do I use this to overwrite any address I want with arbitrary value?

Thanks and Regards,
Hrishikesh Murali

Answer (score 1):

It's a POSIX extension (not found in C99) which will simply allow you to select which argument from the argument list to use for the source of the data.

With regular `printf`, each `%` format specifier grabs the current argument from the list and advances the "pointer" to the next one. That means if you want to print a single value in two different ways, you need something like:

```
printf ("%c %d\n", chVal, chVal);
```

By using positional specifiers, you can do this as:

```
printf ("%1$c %1$d\n", chVal);
```

because *both* format strings will use the first argument as their source.

Another example on the wikipedia page is:

```
printf ("%2$d %2$#x; %1$d %1$#x",16,17);
```

which will give you the output:

```
17 0x11; 16 0x10
```

It basically allows you to disconnect the order of the format specifiers from the provided values, letting you bounce around the argument list in any way you want, using the values over and over again, in any arbitrary order.

Now whether you can use this as an user attack vector, I'm doubtful, since it only adds a means for *the programmer* to change the source of the data, not where the data is sent to.

It's no less secure than the regular style `printf` and I can see no real vulnerabilities unless you have the power to change the format string somehow. But, if you could do that, the regular `printf` would also be wide open to abuse.

Comment: Thanks! From an app-security perspective, this method of accessing random parameters from the stack can be used when you have a potential format string vulnerability. For example:
char *str = argv[1];
printf ( str );
Here, the programmer assumes that the input doesn't contain format strings. But when given such a program, an attacker can insert format strings in the argument string, thus allowing us to see and use values from the program's stack. If we use a "%NNN$hhn" format string, we can overwrite any address on the stack (possibly the return address) to execute our own code.

Comment: No, I don't believe so. While you could possibly see the stack, it doesn't necessarily follow that you can change it. And printf on a user entered string is vulnerable even without the positional parameters.

Comment: Yes, printf on a user-entered string is vulnerable without the positional parameters, just that positional parameters make it easier to exploit.

If you can enter your own format string, then you could use the "%n" format to write into an address on the stack. This address on which you choose to write is based on how the format string is. Am I not correct in saying this?

Comment: @HrishikeshMurali: no. The positional parameter does not dictate where you write to, but where you read from. There is little difference between using `printf("%4$d",7)` and `printf("%d%d%d%d",7)` - they both involve accessing the stack beyond the `7` to get an argument to print. They (both) in no way allow you to write that data elsewhere, other than standard output.

Comment: In any case, POSIX follows the ISO model in that the word "shall" imposes a requirement on the implementation and/or program. All the format specifiers say things like "the argument shall be a pointer to blah blah" meaning that it's undefined what happens if the argument is something else, or you don't provide an argument. That's made even _more_ clear with the POSIX statement "the results are undefined if there are insufficient arguments for the format".

Comment: Supposing I have: char *str = argv[1]; printf(str); Now, what if I could keep printing dummy values from the stack till we reach the format string of the calling function? Let the format string be "\x12\x34\x56\x78"+"%p"*x+"%n" (where x is the number of 4 byte chunks till we reach the format string stored in the calling function's stack), then we would essentially write the number of bytes written till now, into the address 0x12345678 (since printf assumes that's the next argument on the stack). The number 'x' can be found by debugging the program.

Comment: @Hrishikesh, if you're giving user control over the format string, it's _already_ a hole leading to possible UB. It makes no difference whether you use next-in-sequence or positional format strings. In any case, my point still stands: `printf` itself does not write to the local stack area, it writes to stdout, so it would be _very_ difficult to engineer a vulnerability. Perhaps if you were sprintfing into a local buffer it may be problematic but UB _means_ UB - totally undefined. It quite valid for a program doing that to totally destroy your computer and a sphere around it of 25 miles :-)